# Help to identify this garden plant

Tags: identification

I've quite a tall plant in the back garden that has a number of flowers like in the image below.

My neighbour seems to think this may be a weed.

Can somebody please help in identifying this?

I'm in the UK if that matters.

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like Callistemon citrinus 'splendens' to me, it's exactly like the one on my balcony. Those bumpy bits were the red bottlebrush flowers, and it's better to prune those out as soon as they've finished, because they produce new leaves at the tip of the flower -yours have grown on a bit, but if you don't prune them back to just below where the seedheads are, you'll have a bit of bare stem where they used to be later on. It's certainly not a weed - it's hardy in mild parts of the UK, may not survive a cold winter elsewhere, but should be put somewhere sheltered and as sunny as possible for the winter, if its in a pot. In the ground, needs a sunny, sheltered, preferably south facing spot, but if yours is quite tall, its obviously been there a few years and survived just fine. Info here https://www.rhs.org.uk/Plants/99397/Callistemon-citrinus-Splendens/Details